# sending form values from jsp to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a form on my jsp, and when opened, it displays previously saved values to the user, and allows them to be updated within the form. One of the fields (estVal) needs to be shown/hidden based on the sum of 2 values (priorAmt + currAmt) inputted. I'm using the onchange event to trigger the function (showField()):

```
<tr id="priorVal"><td>
2013 Value:
<html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.priorAmt" onchange="showField();" />
</td></tr>

<tr id="currVal"><td>
2014 Value:
<html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.currAmt" onchange="showField();" />
</td></tr>

<tr id="estVal"><td>
2015 Estimated Value:
<html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.estAmt" onchange="showField();" />
</td></tr>
```

My javascript function:

```
function showField() {
alert('2013: ' + $("[name='user.priorAmt']").val() + '. 2014: ' + $("[name='user.currAmt']").val());
}
```

The problem is the the alert only shows the saved value, but not the dynamic/updated value inside of the textbox.

How can I get the updated value based on what the user has entered?

I have tested, and noted that I can send updated values over to the javascript function using a "this" keyword:

```
<tr id="priorVal"><td>
2013 Value:
<html:text maxlength="11" size="11" property="user.priorAmt" onchange="showField(this);" />
</td></tr>
```

But how can I send more than one value - i.e. "this", and the user.currAmt value?

Comment: That code should give you the current value, not the default one.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your reply. It only gives me the saved values. If I update the form value, it still only sends the saved values.